# Read data into two separate lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am just beginning with python and was wondering how I can read a set of points into 2 different lists(say p and q).

```
1.0,4.0
2.0,3.0
6.0,5.0
14.0,3.0
```

I want something like

`p=[1.0,2.0,6.0,14.0]` and `q= [4.0,3.0,5.0,3.0]`

Comment: What is the data structure your data table is in? is it a dataframe? or a numpy array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do so would be:

```
lines =  open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines()
p = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]
q = [line.split(',')[1] for line in lines]
```

Although the syntax is highly readable, it is not recommended to iterate over like this as it is not efficient. Looping over lines in one go would be a good start:

```
for line in open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines():
    p.append(line.split(',')[0])
    q.append(line.split(',')[1])
```

However if you might want to to go for a less readable but efficient & scalable oneliner, here it comes:

```
p,q = map(list,zip(*[line.split(',') for line in open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines()]))
```

### Timings: (With your file scaled up to 30x times data it has)

1. 

```
%%timeit
lines =  open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines()
p = [line.split(',')[0] for line in lines]
q = [line.split(',')[1] for line in lines]
```

returns: `151 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

2.

```
%%timeit
for line in open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines():
    p.append(line.split(',')[0])
    q.append(line.split(',')[1])
```

returns: `149 µs ± 47.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

3.

```
%%timeit
p,q = map(list,zip(*[line.split(',') for line in open('your_file.txt').read().splitlines()]))
```

returns: `105 µs ± 2.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

While numpy and other libraries might be a faster option if you have a lot of operations but in simple cases like this, they are gonna cost you more instead of any efficiency since they are not intended to use for such simple tasks:

```
%%timeit
f = np.loadtxt('your_file.txt', delimiter=',')
p, q = f[:,0], f[:,1] 
p,q
```

returns: `920 µs ± 38.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: a "\n" appears after every number in the second list. Is there a way to work around them?

Comment: actually, this is the most expensive way to do the same thing, not the easiest. Why do you need to iterate over the complete data 2 times after reading it? this solution is highly inefficient. if you want to readlines, then just append the values to p and q in one go right?

Comment: Plus your code doesn't work because you have error in variable names.

Comment: @amitmishra please try not to mark answers that are inefficient and have errors as the correct answers. other SO user who look for similar questions end up getting bad solutions and the overall quality of SO is impacted.

Comment: Thanks Akshey for pointing out! I updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative one-line solution. The `.T` transposes the array returned by `np.loadtxt` so you can unpack it into two (or whatever the number of columns in your txt file).

```py
import numpy as np

p, q = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',').T
```

The data file is defined as

```
1.0,4.0
2.0,3.0
6.0,5.0
14.0,3.0
```

**Edit**

I recently discovered in the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) that you can also set the `unpack` keyword to `True` in order to do the same trick in a cleaner way:

```py
p, q = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```